# About Docker Jboss/keycloak SSL configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to stand up on a keycloak container on docker and add an ssl certificate. However, it does not read the ssl certificate. I'm getting an error in the command part, but I couldn't solve it. What could the problem be caused by? Is there anyone who can help me?

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keyclock
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
    networks:
      - local-keycloak

  keycloak:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    container_name: local_keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keyclock
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: 123456
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT: 8080
      KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT: 8443
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
      REDIRECT_SOCKET: 'proxy-https'
#      HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/fairmerter.crt
#      HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /etc/x509/https/fairmerter.key
#      KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: https://fairmerter.com:8040/auth
#      HOSTNAME: fairmerter.com
    volumes:
      - /tmp/docker/certs/:/etc/x509/https
    command:
      - start '--https-certificate-file=/etc/x509/https/fairmerter.crt --https-certificate-key-file=/etc/x509/https/fairmerter.key'
    ports:
      - "8040:8443"
      - "8080:8080"     
#    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - local-keycloak

networks:
  local-keycloak:
```